# Autosys Windows client

Tags: windows, scheduling, autosys

Is there a Windows client for Autosys that allows me to monitor job that runs on my Linux 
agents?

I need to query Autosys  jobs from Windows and start dependent jobs (using another job scheduler).

If it exists where can I download it? I tried the ca.com webste but it not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. A [ca report](http://www.ca.com/files/industryanalystreports/ca-autosys_workload_automation.pdf) shows there are Unix and Windows clients and also a web client. I have also run the Unix client on a Windows machine via X11.

Answer (score 1):

We're using [iXp](http://www.pgti.com/ixp.html) which is Java Web Start application, which is useful for manual monitoring/editing/force starting of Autosys jobs on a network of machines in a graphical way.

As an aside, can you not configure an autosys agent on your Windows box, and when the job on the Linux box completes, trigger a batch file on your windows which starts the job?

Comment: Your iXp URL leads to a dead link. I found it mentioned here: https://communities.ca.com/web/ca-workload-automation-distributed-global-user-community/message-board/-/message_boards/view_message/99890416